# Texture being stretched horizontally in Cinema 4D

Tags: cinema-4d

I have a Poliigon Texture Demo c4d file. The file includes a sphere with a texture which renders correctly (bottom sphere in image). However when I create a sphere (top sphere in image), convert it to a polygonal object and apply the same texture it is being stretched horizontally.

I can fix this by changing the "Length U" setting to 50% in the Texture Tag but I notice that the sphere below does not need this modification so I was wondering how to convert the top sphere to a polygonal object the same way the bottom sphere is.

[Cinema 4d Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3STN.jpg)

I have included a screengrab. The only notable difference is that the  sphere below has additional diagonal division.

I am quite new to 3D so hope this all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to change the Sphere's Type, to a triangular type, like the sphere at the bottom.
If this helps, please consider up-voting and marking you question as solved